# Show data from all mySQL tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have a ton of tables that vary in columns by a small amount.  I want to be able to select all the data from every table and just display null values (or blanks) when one table doesn't have a column from another table.

I know this can normally be done using the JOIN operator when you have tables that have relationships between each other, but my tables have no relationships between each other except that they have a lot of common column names.

Comment: Better question: why do you even have multiple tables that only differ in small details? Why not go from the start with a bigger table that can leave off data that is not applicable? (And no, you can't do something like that automatically, AFAIK.)

Comment: I would do that but I did not think it would work in my case. I have hundreds of manufactured parts, each with hundreds of serial numbers that all need recorded data in the database. However, since each part has different requirements and details, making additional sub tables would have been horrendous.

Comment: It'll be faster in-the-long-run and better for brain-health to look at reorganizing your table structure entirely.

Comment: I reorganized it in a way that I can pull all the data for all the parts that have the same columns. As for the other parts, I don't think I will get it to work unless I use Amadan's technique

Comment: If you're doing it in php, and don't insist on doing it in a single query, then you can get table names as shown from my answer, and on each table name run a `SELECT *`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Anyway, this is the closest I can think of: [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7b08f/1).

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns
 WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'database_name'
 ORDER BY TABLE_NAME
```

This gives you list of all table names. You can then run queries on all of those.